# Can we disable USB access with "User configuration" GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a requirement to disable/enable the user access to Computer USB via GPO and they want to control it with User configuration not computer configuration.

Is this a possibility with Windows GPO?
else what is the best way i can enable this?

any help.Appreciated.

TR/pasha//

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to restrict certain users from using usb storage devices, correct?
In that case, you can use this administrative template provided by MS:
https://support.microsoft.com/da-dk/help/555324
Once imported the setting it located here:
User Configuration -> Administratice Templates -> System -> Removable Storage Access

-EDIT-
The above path appears to be a standard policy setting, et least when I checked on our Server 2012 R2 DC. So it's natively possible.
Clients just have to be atl east Windows Vista

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The policy to "disable USB access" is found in Group Policy Management Editor \ User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ System \ Removable Storage Access \ All Removable Storage classes: Deny All Access. Enabling this policy (linked to your desired OU) will block all removable storage devices, i.e., USB Sticks, DVD Drive's.